# seam-gen doesn't generate EntityQuery interfaces for @ManyToMany members

Tags: seam

@org.jboss.seam.annotations.security.management.UserRoles exposed in the User interface returns a simple List method.

seam-gen doesn't generate EntityQuery interfaces for @ManyToMany members like the getUserRoles mentioned above.

How do we enable this, so that the resultant roles are shown in a paginated fashion.

Edit 1:

```
This is the declaration in User.java

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
@UserRoles
private List<Role> userRoles = new ArrayList<Role>(0);
```

This is the declaration in Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class Role {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by Pete Muir, Seam lead developer

> Seam-gen does not support @ManyToMany relationship

It does not generate the User Interface when using @ManyToMany. Although Seam-gen makes your life easier, sometimes, you have to do your job manually.

Before going on

1. Seam-gen uses Hibernate's reverse-engineering-tool
2. If a foreign key **is missing** in the table, Seam-gen can not suppose one table is related to another

...

So my advice is:

1. Split your @ManyToMany relationship into @OneToMany - @ManyToOne relationship
2. Set up reverse-engineering configuration

The reverse-engineering configuration file that Seam-gen uses is resources/seam-gen.reveng.xml inside the generated project.

Maybe you want to see

[Controlling reverse engineering](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/reverseengineering.html)

[Reverse engineering support in database and drivers](https://www.hibernate.org/383.html)

**Added to original answer**

Seam uses Ant to generate your app. Its build.xml file is located in the <SEAM_HOME>/seam-gen/build.xml

There, you will see a target called **generate-ui** as follows

```
<target name="generate-ui"
```

It uses a Ant Tool called [hbmtemplate](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/ant.html#hbmtemplate). It is a Template based Engine in which **can be controlled by a user provided template or class**. So if you want a custom behavior, you should provide your own Freemarker template. In <SEAM_HOME>/seam-gen/view directory, you can see a lot of Template files (.flt extension)

regards,

Comment: Currently, I have lots of working code which is using the ManyToMany relationship. Splitting the relationship might be the right workaround for this solution, but is there any way that I could get the existing @ManyToMany List<Role> to render in a pagination fashion. I would need a mechanism to somehow tie up this list on top of the EntityQuery framework in Seam (Note: I would like not to re-do the existing code as we have already spent some time getting this to work based on @ManyToMany relationship)

Comment: @Joshua Thanks for your reply. Saturday i will see how can i help you get your goal.

Comment: @Arthur looking forward to your response (As I mentioned earlier, we have too much code based on the existing @ManyToMany relationships)

Comment: @Arthur I am aware of the freemarker templates shipped as part of seam-gen. I guess my real problem is since @ManyToMany is specified within the parent entity (i.e. User.java), I am unable to figure out the mechanism for generating EntityQuery based classes for ManyToMany. My understanding is that the above interface works only if you define your classes as @Entity. I am not sure if you can use a POJO abstracting the ManyToMany relationship to do the same trick.

Comment: @Joshua 1º My understanding is that the above interface works only if you define your classes as @Entity. I think so. It would help if you post your User and Role class, Seam settings (components.xml), which sean-gem comand you are using and how do you want to show your the resultant roles (view code)

Comment: @Arthur - I have added info on the declarations, as part of the question. I am using the default seam-gen commands shipped as part of the seam 2.2.0 distribution